# Function to check string is only formed by lowercase letters

Tags: solidity-0.6.x

I'm trying to write a solidity contract that tests if a string consists of only lowercase letters. In javascript, I can do this with `myString.match(/^[a-z]+$/)`

Is it possible to do something like this in solidity?

Comment: probably you need to convert each char to byte and check if it is an element the list of lowercase chars http://www.fileformat.info/info/charset/UTF-8/list.htm (very costly).. but there is probably a better solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a function that works in 0.6.0 to check all strings characters :

```
function _checkName(string memory _name) public pure returns(bool){
        uint allowedChars =0;
        bytes memory byteString = bytes(_name);
        bytes memory allowed = bytes("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");  //here you put what character are allowed to use
        for(uint i=0; i < byteString.length ; i++){
           for(uint j=0; j<allowed.length; j++){
              if(byteString[i]==allowed[j] )
              allowedChars++;         
           }
        }
        if(allowedChars<byteString.length)
        return false;
        return true;
    }
```

but it is a bit slow when dealing with long strings.

Answer (score 0):

Check this solution https://gist.github.com/ottodevs/c43d0a8b4b891ac2da675f825b1d1dbf .

Then you can do something like:
if (_string === _toLower(_string)) {
// condition logic
}

Comment: That's too old it has problems in 0.6.0